Containerized Kafka Consumer Cannot Connect to Kafka Container
I am trying to implement a microservice architecture using docker and spring boot. I have a kafka container running, as well as a consumer container running. There is also a producer facing the same issue, but I am sure if I fix the consumer, I can do the same for the producer. The consumer is an independent Spring module with its own config and dockerfile. The consumer, kafka, and producer containers are created and ran using docker compose. In my docker-compose file, I am trying to the bootstrap-server config to connect to kafka:9092 rather than localhost:29092, which is the default in the application.yml of the consumer
The problem I am having is that the consumer container can't connect to the kafka container. In the consumer container, I am getting these logs:
2024-11-08 12:47:21 2024-11-08T20:47:21.708Z  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-order-consumer-group-1, groupId=order-consumer-group] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-11-08 12:47:21 2024-11-08T20:47:21.708Z  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-order-consumer-group-1, groupId=order-consumer-group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Node may not be available.

Everything is running on my localmachine.
I believe the problem involves the consumer trying to use "(localhost/127.0.0.1:29092)" to connect to the kafka server.
I have tried manually altering the application.yml spring: kafka: consumer: bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092 to kafka:9092, but I get a bootstrap-servers when running the consumer:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

OrderConsumer.Java file:
package com.Memorium.order_consumer;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.Memorium.order_consumer.payload.Order;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class OrderConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "order", groupId = "order-consumer-group")
    public void orderConsumer(Order order) {
        log.info("Consumer consume Kafka message -> {}", order);
    }
}

application.yml for OrderConsumer:
server:
  port: 9002

spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092 # we need this to be kafka:2902, but it will not work
      group-id: order-consumer-group
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      properties:
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.json.trusted.packages: com.Memorium.order_consumer.payload
        spring.json.value.default.type: com.Memorium.order_consumer.payload.Order

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.kafka: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: TRACE


OrderConsumer config printed into the logs:
2024-11-08 12:44:33 2024-11-08T20:44:33.029Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
2024-11-08 12:44:33     allow.auto.create.topics = true
2024-11-08 12:44:33     auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
2024-11-08 12:44:33     auto.offset.reset = earliest
2024-11-08 12:44:33     bootstrap.servers = [localhost:29092]
2024-11-08 12:44:33     check.crcs = true
2024-11-08 12:44:33     client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
2024-11-08 12:44:33     client.id = consumer-order-consumer-group-1
2024-11-08 12:44:33     client.rack = 
2024-11-08 12:44:33     connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     enable.auto.commit = false
2024-11-08 12:44:33     enable.metrics.push = true
2024-11-08 12:44:33     exclude.internal.topics = true
2024-11-08 12:44:33     fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
2024-11-08 12:44:33     fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
2024-11-08 12:44:33     fetch.min.bytes = 1
2024-11-08 12:44:33     group.id = order-consumer-group
2024-11-08 12:44:33     group.instance.id = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     group.protocol = classic
2024-11-08 12:44:33     group.remote.assignor = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     interceptor.classes = []
2024-11-08 12:44:33     internal.leave.group.on.close = true
2024-11-08 12:44:33     internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
2024-11-08 12:44:33     isolation.level = read_uncommitted
2024-11-08 12:44:33     key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
2024-11-08 12:44:33     max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
2024-11-08 12:44:33     max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     max.poll.records = 500
2024-11-08 12:44:33     metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     metric.reporters = []
2024-11-08 12:44:33     metrics.num.samples = 2
2024-11-08 12:44:33     metrics.recording.level = INFO
2024-11-08 12:44:33     metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
2024-11-08 12:44:33     receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
2024-11-08 12:44:33     reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
2024-11-08 12:44:33     request.timeout.ms = 30000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     retry.backoff.max.ms = 1000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     retry.backoff.ms = 100
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.jaas.config = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.class = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
2024-11-08 12:44:33     sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
2024-11-08 12:44:33     security.providers = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     send.buffer.bytes = 131072
2024-11-08 12:44:33     session.timeout.ms = 45000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.cipher.suites = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.engine.factory.class = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.key.password = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.keystore.key = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.keystore.location = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.keystore.password = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.keystore.type = JKS
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.provider = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.truststore.certificates = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.truststore.location = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.truststore.password = null
2024-11-08 12:44:33     ssl.truststore.type = JKS
2024-11-08 12:44:33     value.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer


OrderProducer.java file:
package com.Memorium.order_producer;

import com.Memorium.order_producer.payload.Order;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class OrderProducer {
    public static final String TOPIC = "order";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Order> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendOrder(Order order){
        Message<Order> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(order)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "order")
                .build();
        kafkaTemplate.send(message);
        log.info("Producer produced Kafka message -> {}", message);
    }
}

ProducerController.java file:
package com.Memorium.order_producer;

import com.Memorium.order_producer.payload.Order;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RequestMapping("/api/order")
@RestController
public class ProducerController {
    @Autowired
    private OrderProducer orderProducer;

    @PostMapping("/publish")
    public ResponseEntity<String> publish(@RequestBody Order order) {
        orderProducer.sendOrder(order);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(String.format("Order published, %s", order));
    }
}

application.yml for Order Producer:
server:
  port: 9003

spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      acks: -1
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      properties:
        spring.json.add.type.headers: false # GOD DAM THIS TOOK ME HOURS TO FIX, this is why consumer keeps trying to access the producer's order class

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.kafka: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: TRACE


docker-compose:
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - "22181:2181"
    networks:
      - kafka_network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - kafka_network

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
    networks:
      - kafka_network

  producer:
    build:
      context: ../order-producer
    ports:
      - "9003:9003"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
    networks:
      - kafka_network

  consumer:
    build:
      context: ../order-consumer
    ports:
      - "9002:9002"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
    networks:
      - kafka_network

networks:
  kafka_network:
    driver: bridge


If I try to publish to the producer, I get a similar message:
2024-11-08T21:10:21.179Z  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:29092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-11-08T21:10:22.085Z  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.

I've tried manually altering the application.yml bootstrap-servers to kafka:9092, but I cannot build a .jar file if I do that. I have also tried to see If I could access localhost of my local machine from the consumer and try to access kafka that way, but no luck.
I have been able to run the consumer and produce just fine if I do not containerize then and instead just run them inside intelliJ. Kafka would still be in a container as well.
Any detailed explanation would be appreciated, I am still learning Docker.

After many toilsome hours, I have fixed it by altering the application.yml:
server:
  port: 9002

spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      bootstrap-servers: ${SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:29092} 
      group-id: order-consumer-group
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      properties:
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.json.trusted.packages: com.Memorium.order_consumer.payload
        spring.json.value.default.type: com.Memorium.order_consumer.payload.Order

Just needed to change boot change bootstrap-servers to
bootstrap-servers: ${SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:29092}

